# How can I change feature names fonts and image size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, charts

I am working on plotting features' importance between two different perspectives as in this image [features importance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q86XY.png).
How can I change the size of feature fonts and image size to allow all feature names to fit into the image size since I have several features?

This is my code. I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

```
# Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from math import pi
 
# Set data
df = pd.DataFrame({
'group': ['News','Response'],
'user/favourites_count': [.73,5.75],
'name_length_in _char': [.32,4.27],
'user/followers_count': [13.82 ,4],
'screen_name_length_in _char': [.64,3.31],
'user/friends_count': [.84, 2.14],
'user/description_length_in _char': [1.1, 1.83],
'user/geo_enabled': [.29,1.6],
'user/listed_count': [11.35,.95],
'reply_count': [9.43,1.44],
'reputation_score': [4.34,1.31],
'user_effect': [4.42,1.2],
'user_engagment': [2,.83],
'favorite_count': [2.24,.81],
'user/statuses_count': [2.51,.75],
'user/media_count': [7.18 ,0.056],
'user/verified': [8.73, 0.03],
'user_url_statues': [9.52, 3.4], 
'user_describtion_statues': [1.1, 3.6],
    
    
    
})
 
# ------- PART 1: Create background
 
# number of variable
categories=list(df)[1:]
N = len(categories)
 
# What will be the angle of each axis in the plot? (we divide the plot / number of variable)
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]
 
# Initialise the spider plot
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=6) 
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=6)
 
# If you want the first axis to be on top:
ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
 
# Draw one axe per variable + add labels
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories)
 
# Draw ylabels
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
plt.yticks([15,25,35], ["15","25","35"], color="grey", size=5)
plt.ylim(0,14)
 

# ------- PART 2: Add plots
 
# Plot each individual = each line of the data
# I don't make a loop, because plotting more than 3 groups makes the chart unreadable
 
# Ind1
values=df.loc[0].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]
ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', label="News")
ax.fill(angles, values, 'b', alpha=0.1)
 # Ind2
values=df.loc[1].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]
ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', label="Response")
ax.fill(angles, values, 'r', alpha=0.1)

 
# Add legend
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 0.1))

# Show the graph
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have expected graph image? How do you want to fit the feature names?

Comment: No, I don't have. I want the size of the features font to be smaller to fit the image size.